# How to get updated field using update context message

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I do not know how to grab the maximum amount after update maximum value.

[image]
when I created a new maximum amount the 0.01 will automatically update the next minimum amount.

[image]
When I updated maximum amount the minimum amount not update with a new minimum amount which is 25,000.01

```
if (context.MessageName == "Create") {
    Guid RebateLevelsId = new Guid();
    RebateLevelsId = targetEntity.Id;

    if (targetEntity.Attributes.Contains("new_usagerebate")) {
        EntityReference usageRebateEnt = (EntityReference) targetEntity.Attributes["new_usagerebate"];
        Guid usageRebateId = usageRebateEnt.Id;

        EntityCollection rebateLevelEnt = GetEntityCollectionRebateLevel(service, "new_rebatelevels", "new_usagerebate", usageRebateId, new ColumnSet(true));

        Entity rebateLevelEntity = new Entity("new_rebatelevels", RebateLevelsId);
        attributes A = new attributes();

        if (rebateLevelEnt.Entities.Count > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rebateLevelEnt.Entities.Count; i++) {
                if (i == rebateLevelEnt.Entities.Count - 1) {
                    A.level = i + 1;
                }
                if (i == rebateLevelEnt.Entities.Count - 2) {
                    A.Max_Amount = rebateLevelEnt.Entities[i].GetAttributeValue < decimal > ("new_maxamount");
                }
            }

            rebateLevelEntity["new_level"] = A.level.ToString();
            rebateLevelEntity["new_minamount"] = A.Max_Amount + 0.01 m;
            service.Update(rebateLevelEntity);
        } else {
            rebateLevelEntity["new_level"] = 1. ToString();
            service.Update(rebateLevelEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your plugin checks for a Create message. In your post you say that you update the maximum amount. Have you tried checking for an Update message (and making sure your plugin is registered on an update of the relevant entity?

Comment: that is the point should I use pre/post entity images?

Comment: If you want your plugin to trigger on an Update event, you must register it on an Update event (just like you’ve registered it on a Create event now). Then, you must check for an Update in your plugin (as well as Create). Presumably, you’re missing one or both of these which is why your plugin doesn’t trigger.

Answer (score 2):

I gave this problem some thought and coded an example of how I might handle it.

I was looking to build a robust solution that would allow adjustments to both the level above and the level below the one we're creating or updating. This cases this solution covers include:

1. Start from 0 level records and add as we go
2. Min may be lower than prior level's max - in which case we adjust the prior level's max.
3. Min may be lower than prior level's min - in which case we throw an exception.
4. Max may be higher than next level's min - in which case we adjust the next level's min.
5. Max may be higher than next level's max - in which case we throw an exception.
6. Min may be lower than prior level's max AND max may be higher than next level's min, which case we adjust both the prior level and the next level.
7. Min may be lower than prior level's min AND max may be higher than next level's max, in which case we throw an exception containing info about both issues.
8. Possibility of having more than 3 levels.
9. Handle both Create and Update events.

One thing that's missing is logic to ensure that users don't skip a level. Another is handling deletions.

Rather than create entities in a D365 system, I built this to run with dummy data in a console app, and `IOrganizationService` calls commented out. However, it uses the `EntityCollection` and `Entity` classes, so you should be able to plug in live data pretty easily.

I took an object-oriented approach. The `Level` class started out as a wrapper to expose a `new_rebatelevel's` data without having to use `GetAttributeValue<>` constantly. It grew into a robust class that shoulders much of the load.

The `target` represents the level that has been created or updated.

Here's the Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new App_CalcMinMax();
        app.Run();
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress <Enter> to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();                
        }
    }
}
```

And the "app":

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class App_CalcMinMax 
{
    public void Run()
    {            
        var rebates = new UsageRebate(toCollection(new List<Entity>())); //start with an empty list
        //process various level create and update events
        //and display the results of each event
        //.Process() takes the level #, the min, and the max
        rebates.Process(1, 0, 10000);
        rebates.Process(2, 11000.01m, 20000);
        rebates.Process(3, 21000.01m, 30000);          
        rebates.Process(1, 0, 9000);            
        rebates.Process(2, 10000, 15000);            
        rebates.Process(3, 17000, 35000);
        rebates.Process(3, 12000, 24000);
        rebates.Process(2, 8000, 20000);
        rebates.Process(1, 0, 25000);
        rebates.Process(2, 14000, 19000);
    }

    private class Level
    {
        private Entity e;
        private Level lower;
        private Level upper;
        public int Num => e.GetAttributeValue<int>("new_level");
        public decimal Min => e.GetAttributeValue<Money>("new_minamount").Value;
        public decimal Max => e.GetAttributeValue<Money>("new_maxamount").Value;
        public bool IsValidLower => lower == null ? true : Min > lower.Min;
        public bool IsValidUpper => upper == null ? true : Max < upper.Max;
        public bool IsValid => IsValidLower && IsValidUpper;
        public bool AdjustLower => lower == null ? false : Min - 0.01m != lower.Max;
        public bool AdjustUpper => upper == null ? false : Max + 0.01m != upper.Min;

        public Level(Entity e)
        {
            this.e = e;
        }
        public void ValidateLower(Level lower)
        {
            this.lower = lower;
        }
        public void ValidateUpper(Level upper)
        {
            this.upper = upper;
        }
        public void SetMin(decimal value, IOrganizationService service = null)
        {
            e["new_minamount"] = new Money(value);
            //service.Update(e);
        }
        public void SetMax(decimal value, IOrganizationService service = null)
        {
            e["new_maxamount"] = new Money(value);
            //service.Update(e)
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $" Level: {Num}\tmin: { Min.ToString("N2"),9}\tmax: { Max.ToString("N2"),9}";
        }
    }

    private class UsageRebate
    {
        private IOrganizationService service;
        private EntityCollection ec;
        private IEnumerable<int> levelNums => Levels.Select(l => l.Num);
        public IEnumerable<Entity> Entities => ec.Entities;
        public IEnumerable<Level> Levels => Entities.Select(e => new Level(e));
        public UsageRebate(EntityCollection ec, IOrganizationService service = null)
        {
            this.ec = ec;
            this.service = service;
        }

        public void Process(int num, decimal min, decimal max)
        {
            var target = toEntity(num, min, max);
            var level = new Level(target);                
            Level prior = null;
            Level next = null;
            Console.WriteLine($"Target: {level.ToString()}");

            if (tryGetLevel(level.Num-1,out prior))
            {
                level.ValidateLower(prior);
            }

            if (tryGetLevel(level.Num + 1, out next))
            {
                level.ValidateUpper(next);
            }

            if (level.IsValid)
            {
                if (exists(level.Num))
                {
                    update(target);
                }
                else
                {
                    add(target);
                }
                if (level.AdjustLower)
                {
                    prior.SetMax(level.Min - 0.01m);
                }
                if (level.AdjustUpper)
                {
                    next.SetMin(level.Max + 0.01m);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string message = "Exception: ";
                if (!level.IsValidLower)
                {
                    message += $"Level {level.Num} Min is less than Level {prior.Num} Min\n";
                }
                if (!level.IsValidUpper)
                {
                    message += $"Level {level.Num} Max exceeds Level {next.Num} Max";                        
                }
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                //throw new Exception(message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Results:\n{ToString()}");
        }

        private bool tryGetLevel(int num, out Level level)
        {
            var ex = exists(num);
            level = ex ? get(num) : null;                
            return ex;
        }

        private void add(Entity entity)
        {
            ec.Entities.Add(entity);
            //service.Create(entity);
        }

        private void update(Entity entity)
        {
            var e = get(entity);
            e["new_minamount"] = entity["new_minamount"];
            e["new_maxamount"] = entity["new_maxamount"];
            //service.Update(entity);
        }

        private bool exists(int num)
        {
            return levelNums.Contains(num);
        }

        private Level get(int num)
        {
            return Levels.Where(l => l.Num == num).Single();
        }

        private Entity get(Entity entity)
        {
            return Entities.Where(e => new Level(e).Num == new Level(entity).Num).Single();
        }

        private Entity toEntity(int level, decimal min, decimal max)
        {
            return new Entity
            {
                LogicalName = "new_rebatelevel",
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Attributes =
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("new_level", level),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("new_minamount", new Money(min)),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("new_maxamount", new Money(max))
                }
            };
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            Levels.ToList().ForEach(l => sb.AppendLine(l.ToString()));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    private EntityCollection toCollection(List<Entity> list)
    {
        var ec = new EntityCollection();
        ec.EntityName = "new_rebatelevel";
        ec.Entities.AddRange(list);
        return ec;
    }
}
```

And the output:

---

Target:  Level: 1       min:      0.00  max: 10,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max: 10,000.00

Target:  Level: 2       min: 11,000.01  max: 20,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max: 11,000.00
 Level: 2       min: 11,000.01  max: 20,000.00

Target:  Level: 3       min: 21,000.01  max: 30,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max: 11,000.00
 Level: 2       min: 11,000.01  max: 21,000.00
 Level: 3       min: 21,000.01  max: 30,000.00

Target:  Level: 1       min:      0.00  max:  9,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max:  9,000.00
 Level: 2       min:  9,000.01  max: 21,000.00
 Level: 3       min: 21,000.01  max: 30,000.00

Target:  Level: 2       min: 10,000.00  max: 15,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max:  9,999.99
 Level: 2       min: 10,000.00  max: 15,000.00
 Level: 3       min: 15,000.01  max: 30,000.00

Target:  Level: 3       min: 17,000.00  max: 35,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max:  9,999.99
 Level: 2       min: 10,000.00  max: 16,999.99
 Level: 3       min: 17,000.00  max: 35,000.00

Target:  Level: 3       min: 12,000.00  max: 24,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max:  9,999.99
 Level: 2       min: 10,000.00  max: 11,999.99
 Level: 3       min: 12,000.00  max: 24,000.00

Target:  Level: 2       min:  8,000.00  max: 20,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max:  7,999.99
 Level: 2       min:  8,000.00  max: 20,000.00
 Level: 3       min: 20,000.01  max: 24,000.00

Target:  Level: 1       min:      0.00  max: 25,000.00
Exception: Level 1 Max exceeds Level 2 Max
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max:  7,999.99
 Level: 2       min:  8,000.00  max: 20,000.00
 Level: 3       min: 20,000.01  max: 24,000.00

Target:  Level: 2       min: 14,000.00  max: 19,000.00
Results:
 Level: 1       min:      0.00  max: 13,999.99
 Level: 2       min: 14,000.00  max: 19,000.00
 Level: 3       min: 19,000.01  max: 24,000.00

Press Enter to continue...

Comment: I do not know the logic how to retrieve updated maximum amount and pass it to minimum amount?should I use pre/post entity images?Enlighten my noobass please

Comment: Hi, the code I've shared above is valid for `create` and `update` messages. You can pass the target in from an image, or from the result of a `svc.Retrieve()` call. And you also need any existing levels as an `EntityCollection`.  There's no need to branch the code based on message type.